# Sheet protection: UserInterFaceOnly gone

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, password-protection

In VBA Excel if I protect sheets with  `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` option after I close and open the file again the `UserInterFaceOnly` mode is not active, only Password protection.

The code: `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="myPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Why?

Comment: That is just the way it is. You have to reset it in the `Open` event.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do it without reapplying `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` after reopening the workbook. Taken from Excel's Vb [protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method reference:

> If you apply this method with the UserInterfaceOnly argument set to true and then save the workbook, the entire worksheet (not just the interface) will be fully protected when you reopen the workbook. To re-enable the user interface protection after the workbook is opened, you must again apply this method with UserInterfaceOnly set to true

Now, if your concern is that this takes too long (15 seconds, as you say), take a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133650/103313) Code Review answer. I have done this in several workbooks of varying level of complexity, and the time for reapplying protection is negligible in all versions I've tried, including 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the cause of that issue is, but you can circumvent it by adding protection code to the `Workbook_Open()` event, resetting every sheet protection to have `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` in each

Comment: The Excel file has 15 sheets and doing protection in every time takes 10 second which is too much. I' ve already experimenting with this.

Comment: @Pwi 10 seconds for 15 sheets??? I can't see how it would take that long if all you are doing is toggling protection.  I just tested it myself and it was essentially instantaneous.   Is there something else going on that might be slowing it down?

Comment: I tried with a fully empty Workbook. Try with this code:
`code:

    For Each Sh In Worksheets
        Sh.Protect Password:="passw", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next sh

/code`

Comment: In Excel 2013 and up, the password algorithm was changed and it is a lot slower than it used to be.

Comment: Is there any way to protect sheet from user modifcation beside Protect/Unprotect method?

Comment: @Rory for the first time in years, running 2010 is a good thing :)

Comment: @Rory I'm using 2013, this is why happen

Comment: @RGA Running 2010 is always a good thing IMO. Still the best version.

Comment: @Rory Unfortunately i have no option running older version.

Comment: @Pwi You're stuck with what you have then.